# ngRepeat with filter not showing new added data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a table with a list of topics: first column with topic name and second column with a button that sets gradesCtrl.topic to selected topic:

```
<tr ng-repeat="topic in gratesCtrl.topics_list">
     <td>{{topic.name}}</td>
     <td><i class="fa fa-leanpub" ngclick="gradesCtrl.show_grades(topic)"></i></td>                   
</tr>
```

"show_grades" function from controller:

```
vm.show_grades = function(topic){
    vm.selected_topic = topic._id;
};
```

Based on selected topic, i'm creating a table using ngRepeat with data from controller:

```
<tr ng-repeat="grade in gradesCtrl.child_grades | filter: gradesCtrl.selected_topic">
      <td>{{grade.value}}</td>
      <td>{{grade.data_string}}</td>
      <td>{{grade.observations}}</td>
</tr>
```

In controller I add a new grade to child_grades:

```
app.controller('GradesController',['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.new_grade = {}, vm.child_grades = [], vm.topics_list;
    //vm.child_grades - I recieve the data using socketIo events

    socket.on('new_grade', function(grade){         
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            vm.child_grades.push(grade);
        });
    });
});
```

When I add the new grade to child_grades, the grades table won't update and it doesn't contain the new grade when i'm using filter, but when I don't use filter it works fine. After I add the new grade to child_grades, if i check the child_grades, it contains the new grade. I have to mention that the filtering works when the page is first loaded. What can I do to make the table to show the new added document?

Comment: Your filter seems incorrect. Try something like that: `filter:{ _id: gradesCtrl.selected_topic }`. It may not help, but it makes your filter strict and without side-effects

Comment: I tried it, but still not works

Comment: Does the new grade that you push in the array match the filter? i.e. does it have a property that is equal to gradesCtrl.selected_topic?

Comment: @andra-nico Where do you use `tr` with this repeat `ng-repeat="grade in gradesCtrl.child_grades`? Show me please whole table layout

Comment: Are you sure there's no capitalisation or strange characters/spaces issues when you add via angular?

Comment: @jb-nizet yes, it has a property that match the filter, but the only difference is that the new grade doesn't have all properties in the same order as other grades from array. Does the order matter?

Comment: properties have no order at all.

Comment: @Max: This is the whole table layout: <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Observations</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="grade in gradesCtrl.child_grades | filter: gradesCtrl.selected_topic">
                    <td>{{grade.value}}</td>
                    <td>{{grade.data_string}}</td>
                    <td>{{grade.observations}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

Comment: @AndraNico Hmm.. Try instead of `$rootScope.$apply(function(){
            vm.child_grades.push(grade);
        });` 
this 
`vm.child_grades.push(grade);
vm.$digest();`

Comment: @Max Still no change, and it doesn't update the table even without filter, only after another graded was added.

Comment: @AndraNico Ok. And what full structure of `grade`? Is `selected_topic` only string presentation of `ID`?

Comment: I figured it out, JB Nizet was right, it didn't have a property to match the filter, because I thought other property will match it. Sorry for this and thank you all!